# How to turn one column of numbers into one cell in SQL server? (Find all prime number smaller than 1000)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, recursive-query

I'm required to write a query to print all prime numbers less than or equal to 1000. And I need to print the result into one single line and use the ampersand character as the separator (instead of a space). like this:

```
2&3&5&7&11&13
```

Here is my code (the datatype of Number is int so I need to change it to varchar so the ampersand character can show up in one cell with the Number):

```
with temp as
(select 2 as Number
union all 
select Number + 1 from temp where Number<1000)
, temptwo as
(select * from temp t1
where NOT EXISTS
(select 1 from temp t2
where t1.Number > t2.Number
and t1.Number % t2.Number = 0))
, tempthree as
(select Cast(Number AS Varchar) as Number from temptwo)
select 
STUFF((SELECT  '&' + Number
            FROM tempthree tt
            WHERE  tt.Number = t.Number
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
FROM tempthree t
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

But it does not really work. I don't know what is the problem?
And up to this point it works well:

```
with temp as
(select 2 as Number
union all 
select Number + 1 from temp where Number<1000)
, temptwo as
(select * from temp t1
where NOT EXISTS
(select 1 from temp t2
where t1.Number > t2.Number
and t1.Number % t2.Number = 0))
select Cast(Number AS Varchar) as Number from temptwo
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

But it only prints out something like this:

```
2
3
5
7
11
13
...
```

But this is not I want. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is OK to identify the prime numbers. You are just missing string aggregation.

Here is one option using `string_agg()`, available since SQL Server 2017:

```
with temp as (
    select 1 num
    union all 
    select num + 1 from temp where num < 1000
)
select string_agg(num, '&') within group(order by num) res
from temp t
where not exists (select 1 from temp t1 where t.num < t1.num and t.num % t1.num = 0)
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Note that I eliminated the second cte, that is not really needed (you can put the `not exists` condition directly in the outer query).

Answer (score 1):

If you are stuck with a version of SQL Server that doesn't support `STRING_AGG`, you need to use `STUFF`, but your syntax isn't quite right; it should look like:

```
with temp as
(select 2 as Number
union all 
select Number + 1 from temp where Number<1000)
select STUFF((
          SELECT '&' + Cast(Number AS Varchar)
          FROM temp t1
          where NOT EXISTS (select 1 from temp t2
                            where sqrt(t1.Number) >= t2.Number
                              and t1.Number % t2.Number = 0)
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Note I've made some optimisations, bring the parts of your second and third cte's into the `STUFF`, and improving the performance of the `NOT EXISTS` query by only looking at numbers up to the square root of the original number.

Output:

```
2&3&5&7&11&13&17&19&23&29&31&37&41&43&47&53&59&61&67&71&73&79&83&89&97&101&103&107&109&113&127&131&137&139&149&151&157&163&167&173&179&181&191&193&197&199&211&223&227&229&233&239&241&251&257&263&269&271&277&281&283&293&307&311&313&317&331&337&347&349&353&359&367&373&379&383&389&397&401&409&419&421&431&433&439&443&449&457&461&463&467&479&487&491&499&503&509&521&523&541&547&557&563&569&571&577&587&593&599&601&607&613&617&619&631&641&643&647&653&659&661&673&677&683&691&701&709&719&727&733&739&743&751&757&761&769&773&787&797&809&811&821&823&827&829&839&853&857&859&863&877&881&883&887&907&911&919&929&937&941&947&953&967&971&977&983&991&997
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d3fefa8b96b0db3fc7e73775bfaed383)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the third CTE just for casting. Numbers are implicitly casted when used in `concat()`.

But you need the subquery of the actual query to query all from the second CTE and concatenate it. The actual outer query needs to be `FROM`-less as you only want one row, not multiple, which you'd get if you selected from the second CTE.

The ampersand is a special character in XML and therefore encoded. An easy way to go around this is to initially use commas instead of ampersands and then use `replace()` to make the commas into ampersands.

```
WITH tempone
AS
(
SELECT 2 number
UNION ALL
SELECT number + 1
       FROM tempone
       WHERE number < 1000
),
temptwo
AS
(
SELECT *
       FROM tempone t1
       WHERE NOT EXISTS
                 (SELECT *
                         FROM tempone t2
                         WHERE t1.number > t2.number
                               AND t1.number % t2.number = 0)
)
SELECT replace(stuff((SELECT concat(',', tt.number)
                             FROM temptwo tt
                             FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''), ',', '&')
       OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7d985726eadd77d5744aa04eb29c20d8)